# Action to take to track all deleted records from production based on some criteria

Tags: production, excel, backup, sf

As a sf SystemAdmin user with no role assigned in production,
I got the backup before we run the batch in production to delete duplicate account contact and activities from production.
I also exported records from production after the batch execution.

there were some failed chunk of the batch and by chance we only had one log and found there were some data loss.

we want to find out all those records deleted implicitly over parent account deletion so that we can restore them or take required action.

Duplicate remove criteria's:

- Delete merger all account record of same owner and account name and record type. keep the older one as master but only transfer :

1. task,event to the master if it's not already have the matching
   activity by subject+ActivityDate
2. contact records to master account if master don't already have same recordtype contact already as a direct child

- After merging of same record type. One xyz record type's account records should be merged with the abc record type and have the same criteria (#1 & #2) to transfer xyz's account's activity and contact records.

please share supportive resources with suggestion..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.